# Как сделать slice в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, срез, slice

При парсинге данные выходят в таком формате:

```
22 Августа 2019 17:17 25
```

Как срезать, чтобы было так:

```
22 Августа 2019 17:17
```

без цифры 25? Как это лучше реализовать?

Вот функция, которая парсит дату:

```
def get_item_datetime(item_page, datetime_rule, datetime1_rule):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_page, 'lxml')
    item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]})
    if item_datetime is not None:
        item_datetime = soup.find(datetime_rule[0],{datetime_rule[1]:datetime_rule[2]}).text
        item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
    else:
        if (len(datetime1_rule) == 3):
            item_datetime = soup.find(datetime1_rule[0],{datetime1_rule[1]:datetime1_rule[2]}).text
            item_datetime = dateparser.parse(item_datetime, date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])
        else:
            item_datetime = ''
```

Comment: А в конце всегда два числа и пробел?

Comment: В конце цифр может быть 3 иногда 2.А на счет пробела всегда так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в конце всегда только 2 цифры, то легче всего так:

```py
new_date = date[:-3]
```

Если же нет, то так:

```py
last_space_index = date.rfind(" ") #Находим первое вхождение пробела с конца строки
new_date = date[:last_space_index]
print(new_date)
```

Comment: благодарю за время которое вы мне уделили,сейчас по пробую

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать собрать список по пробелам, удалить последний элемент списка и вернуть строку из списка.

```py
date = '22 Августа 2019 17:17 25'
a = date.split()
a.remove(a[-1])
print(' '.join(a))
```

Либо вариант, который не будет учитывать любые символы после даты

```py
date = '22 Августа 2019 17:17 250 ыуецеукц 45'
a = date.split()
print(' '.join(a[:4]))
```

Comment: `date = '22 Августа 2019 17:17 250 ыуецеукц 45'
a = date.split()
print(' '.join(a[:4]))` этот вариант работает.Но видите ли я парсю не 1 ресурс а около 10.И как бы такой вариант,я думаю подойдет только для этого портала

Comment: Надо смотреть какие форматы в других источниках. Вероятно есть смысл приводить все к единообразию. Я бы сделал что-то типа маппинга. Указываешь ресурс или формат данных и какой функцией обработать эти данные.